# package eurosym: how to change the decimal separator?

Tags: eurosym

The decimal separator of the eurosym package is either the comma or the dot. If you write \EUR{3.2} it is written with a dot, and if you write \EUR{3,2}, it is written with a comma according to the French typography.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}  % Présentation générale et mise en page

\usepackage[right]{eurosym}         
\usepackage[french]{babel}


\begin{document}

Avec un point : \EUR{10.30} 

Avec une virgule : \EUR{10,30}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: eurosym-decimal-separator]

So there is no problem from that point of view.

However, with LaTeX the decimal separator is by default a dot. For example, the `xlop` package, `tikz` and almost all other packages respect this convention. And in order to respect the local typography, French for example, a global command allows to modify the decimal separator and to display a comma in place of the dot. This is consistent since all numbers are coded identically and displayed using local typography.

For example, with xlop these command is `\opset{decimalsepsymbol={,}}`

Is it possible to do the same with eurosym? That is, how to write `\EUR{13.25}` in the code and display 13,25 € in the text?

If not, which package allows you to do this?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integrate `eurosym` with `siunitx` that makes `\num` available. However you input the number, it will be output with the chosen decimal marker, here according to `locale=FR`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

\sisetup{locale=FR}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\EUR}[2][]{%
  \if@EURleft\euro\,\fi
  \num[#1]{#2}%
  \if@EURleft\else\,\euro\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Avec un point : \EUR{10.30}

Avec une virgule : \EUR{10,30}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The redefined `\EUR` command has also an optional argument for setting options for `\num`; see the documentation of `siunitx`: `\EUR[<options>]{<number>}`.

If you want to use `numprint`, just change `\num` (and the optional argument makes no sense here):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\EUR}[1]{%
  \if@EURleft\euro\,\fi
  \numprint{#1}%
  \if@EURleft\else\,\euro\fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: is it also possible to integrate eurosym with the `numprint` package?

Comment: @AndréC Yes, of course, but siunitx is much better.

Comment: Why? I have less problems with `numprint` on `beamer`see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440572/how-to-migrate-from-numprint-to-siunitx-while-keeping-the-same-font

Comment: @AndréC Added code for `numprint`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really have to learn TeX because I should have done this myself!