# How do I make ditto marks?

Tags: itemize

In France, students are taught not to repeat the same text twice when there is little difference between a line and the one below. It's a quick way to take notes.

I reproduced this effect by tinkering:

[image: prise-de-note]

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Lorsque le \og \textit{carreau carré} \fg{}   mesure:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\rm 1\,cm$ de côté, l'unité d'aire est appelée le \og \textrm{centimètre carré} \fg{} et est noté $\rm cm^2$;
\item $\rm 1\,dm$ \hspace{1mm}'' \hspace{3mm}'' \hspace{8mm}'' \hspace{8mm}'' \hspace{5mm}''\hspace{8mm}'' \hspace{5.5mm}''\hspace{1mm} \og \textrm{décimètre carré} \fg{} \hspace{2mm}'' \hspace{2mm}'' \hspace{4mm}'' \hspace{1.5mm} $\rm dm^2$;
\item $\rm 1\,m$ \hspace{3mm}'' \hspace{3mm}'' \hspace{8mm}'' \hspace{8mm}'' \hspace{5mm}'' \hspace{7mm}'' \hspace{5.5mm}''\hspace{1mm} \og \textrm{mètre carré} \fg{}  \hspace{9mm}'' \hspace{2mm}'' \hspace{4mm}'' \hspace{1mm} $\rm m^2$;
\item etc.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I get the same effect more simply than by tinkering like I just did?

Comment: I think French typography prefers closing French guillemets for this (`»`). Also, don't type units in maths italic. Better use the `siunitx` package and the  `\SI1\cm}`, for instance, to have the correct font and the correct spacing (a thin unbreakable space).

Comment: @Bernard I haven't found a typographical source for the use of French quotation marks in this case and I've never seen any of my teachers use them on the board. As for siuntix, its use of the fonts without serif with beamer makes the reading difficult, in particular for the liters (merges with the number 1).

Comment: Never put units in italics!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I wrote the units in mathematical mode which is in italics. To avoid italics, I replaced `$cm^2$` by `$\rm cm^2$`. I edited the question to take into account the remarks of Bernard and yourself.

Comment: @AndréC Your litre problem with siunitx can very easily be solved: `\DeclareSIUnit\litre{\ell}
\SI{1}{\litre}`

Comment: @samcarter The problem then arises with mililitres, centilitres, décilitres for which the prefix `m` , `c` and `d` are no longer written in the same style as `\ell`.

Comment: @Bernard I hadn't noticed that the spacing was incorrect, I just corrected it.

Comment: @AndréC Now you are missing the small space between number and unit -- siuntx would take care of that -- just saying :)

Comment: @samcarter It is because of the writing of the units under beamer with a non-serif font that I prefer the `numprint` package which uses a serif font :)  see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440572/how-to-migrate-from-numprint-to-siunitx-while-keeping-the-same-font

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since @samcarter was faster than me, I had to build some special functionality in my answer, borrowing some code from @egreg ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280981/97512)):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

% from egreg's answer at
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280981/97512
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xsameword}{m}
{
  \leavevmode\maieul_xsameword:n { #1 }
}

\tl_new:N \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \maieul_xsameword:n
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
  {
    \__maieul_xsameword_start:n { #1 }
  }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
  { (\c{footnote}\cB..*?\cE.) }
  { \cE\} \1 \c{__maieul_xsameword_start:n} \cB\{ }
  \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__maieul_xsameword_start:n
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
  { ([^\s,.!?]+) }% Delete what should not be printed again here
  { \c{maieul_xsameword_format:n} \cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
  \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__maieul_xsameword_list_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\setxsamewordformat}{m}
{
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \maieul_xsameword_format:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newbox\mytmpbox

\newcommand{\repword}[1]{%
  \sbox{\mytmpbox}{#1}%
  \hbox to \wd\mytmpbox{\hss\hspace{.2em}''\hss}%
}

\setxsamewordformat{\repword{#1}}

\newcommand{\keepword}[2]{%
  \sbox{\mytmpbox}{#2}%
  \hbox to \wd\mytmpbox{\hss#1\hss}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

Lorsque le \og \textit{carreau carré} \fg{}   mesure:
\begin{itemize}
  \item {1}\,$cm$ de côté, l'unité d'aire est appelée le \og \textit{\textrm{centimètre carré}} \fg{} et est noté $cm^2$;

  \item 1\,\keepword{$dm$}{$cm$} \xsameword{de côté, l'unité d'aire est appelée le} \keepword{\og \textit{\textrm{décimètre carré}} \fg{}}{\og \textit{\textrm{centimètre carré}} \fg{}} \xsameword{et est noté} $cm^2$;

  \item 1\,\keepword{$m$}{$cm$} \xsameword{de côté, l'unité d'aire est appelée le}  \keepword{\og \textit{\textrm{mètre carré}} \fg{}}{\og \textit{\textrm{centimètre carré}} \fg{}} \xsameword{et est noté} \keepword{$m^2$}{$cm^2$};
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This allows you to put a whole sentence in the argument of `\xsamewords` and they will be replaced. Also, I built a macro that allows you to insert words taking the same amount of space as another word: `\keepwords{this line}{line above}`.

[image: result]

**edit:** Now I put the first `$dm$` in `\keepwords` and it is aligned properly, thanks @marmot for pointing me there! `:-)`

**edit2:** Example with three lines added.

**edit3:** Added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and inserted a comment showing which line should be edited to remove, e.g., commas.

The line `{ ([^\s,.!?]+) }` represents a [`regular expression`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), or short `regex`. These can be used for advanced pattern matching, if a simple `find` or `find & replace` is not sufficient. Here, this regex represents the words that should be replaced by `''` your ditto marks:

- `[..]` brackets match one character from the inside. `[abc]` operated on `foobar` would match the `b` or the `a` (but only one of them, a *single* character).
- `[^..]` is the negation of the characters inside, so this regex here is matching anything *not* present. `[^abc]` operated on `foobar` would match `f`, `o`, `o`, or `r`.
- `\s` is any white space character (spaces, tabs, sometimes also new lines)
- `,.!?` are self-explanatory I assume ;)
- `+` after a character (remember, brackets match a single character) makes the character match as many multiple ("identical") characters, as possible (usual behavior) but at least one. So, e.g., `o+` in regex operated on the string `fooobar` would match `ooo`, not just one or two `o`s. `[abc]+` operated on `foobar` would match `ba`.

You can see now, this regex matches everything that is *not* a white space or punctuation mark, i.e., everything else, that is words with all other special characters. You can think of the symbols inside the negated brackets to be the word delimiters that you still want to print and not replace in this context.

**edit4:** If you add `\leavevmode` before calling (the old) `\xsameword`, it should work fine at the beginning of a line as well. Now, I added it in the definition of `\xsameword`, so there's no need to take care of it manually.

Comment: Beautiful work, only, it doesn't work anymore when I add a third line with "square meter" . I edited the question.

Comment: @AndréC see my edit. It works, you just need to put your `\og` and `\fg` inside the braces of `\keepword` ;)

Comment: Your solution is beautiful, but it would be better if commas were removed. Indeed, the goal here is to teach very young students to write faster.

Comment: @nox: you should have loaded `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for correct french quotes.

Comment: @AndréC just change the line `{ ([^\s,.!?]+) }` to, e.g., `{ ([^\s!?]+) }` to not print commas and periods again.

Comment: @Bernard you're right, I added this in an edit.

Comment: @nox Thank you very much, can you explain this in this very beautiful solution?

Comment: @AndréC it's a thing called regular expression. See my updated answer.

Comment: I knew regex in PHP, I didn't know it also existed with LaTeX. Your explanation is perfect. A big thank you  :)

Comment: If the first word is included in the macro, it does not align the quotation marks. `\item \xsameword{1}\keepword{$dm$}{$cm$} \xsameword{side down, the area unit is called the}` dont work !

Comment: @AndréC see my last edit, `\leavevmode` is all you need to add there. Put inside the command of `\xsameword`  makes it work out of the box.

Comment: Great job :-) I took the liberty of deleting the l3regex call, see this comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479650/l3regex-sty-not-found?noredirect=1#comment1292576_479650

Answer (score 15):

Instead of guessing the required spaces, you could measure the width of the words you want to replace:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlength{\mywidth}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
\settowidth{\mywidth}{#1}%
\makebox[\mywidth][c]{''}%
}

\newlength{\centwidth}
\settowidth{\centwidth}{<< centimètre carré >>}

\newlength{\foowidth}
\settowidth{\foowidth}{\SI{1}{\centi\meter}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Lorsque le \og \textit{carreau carré} \fg{}   mesure:
\begin{itemize}
\item \makebox[\foowidth][l]{\SI{1}{\centi\meter}} de côté, l'unité d'aire est appelée le \makebox[\centwidth][c]{\og \textit{\textrm{centimètre carré}} \fg} et est noté \si{\centi\meter\square};
\item \makebox[\foowidth][l]{\SI{1}{\deci\meter}} \test{de} \test{côté,} \test{l'unité} \test{d'aire} \test{est} \test{appelée} \test{le} \makebox[\centwidth][c]{\og \textit{\textrm{décimètre carré}} \fg} \test{et} \test{est} \test{noté} \si{\deci\meter\square};
\item \makebox[\foowidth][l]{\SI{1}{\meter}} \test{de} \test{côté,} \test{l'unité} \test{d'aire} \test{est} \test{appelée} \test{le} \makebox[\centwidth][c]{\og \textit{\textrm{mètre carré}} \fg} \test{et} \test{est} \test{noté} \si{\meter\square};
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### [image]

Another approach could be to use a tabular

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Lorsque le \og \textit{carreau carré} \fg{}   mesure:

\begin{tabular}{ll*{11}{@{~}c}@{~}l}
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item} & \SI{1}{\centi\meter} & de & côté,& l'unité &d'aire &est& appelée& le &\og \textit{\textrm{centimètre carré}} \fg{}& et &est& noté& \si{\centi\meter\square};\\
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item} & \SI{1}{\deci\meter} & " & " & " & " & " & " & " &\og \textit{\textrm{décimètre carré}} \fg{}& " & " & " & \si{\deci\meter\square};\\
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item} & \SI{1}{\meter} & " & " & " & " & " & " & " &\og \textit{\textrm{mètre carré}} \fg{}& " & " & " & \si{\meter\square};\\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very smart idea! +1

Comment: now i see, that you can suggest to replace `{1}\,{$cm$}` with `siunitx` system of writing  units: `\SI{1}{cm}`. of course, in this case  to preamble should be added `\usepackage{siunitx}` (all is very off-topic, of course :-) )

Comment: Very nice work, only, it doesn't work anymore when I add a third line with "square meter" . I edited the question.

Comment: @AndréC Please see my edit. The same technique can be used to align the square meter line.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the suggestion about siunitx. Originally I discarded this idea because I thought the different font was used on purpose to emphasis the unit, but after the edit of the question I agree that siunitx is a good idea to add.

Comment: Strange you don't obtain real french quotes in `« mètre carré »`  and the like… Maybe loading [T1]{fontenc}?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, with T1 font encoding I get real guillemet.