# Quote (ditto marks) to avoid repeating a text

Tags: spacing, text

In a document I am writing I have a list close to this one:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item \emph{c} before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced as in \emph{church}
    \item \emph{g} before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced as in \emph{gin}
\end{itemize}
```

Of course, there is a large portion of repeated text. Is it possible to replace it with a single character ” centered ans taking the right width?

The final result should look like:

```
c before e or i is pronounced as in church
g             ”               as in gin
```

Comment: You mean not repeating ‘is pronounced as in’?

Comment: It's a general question but here it would be not to repeat "before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced as in"

Comment: questions about notional conventions are off topic here, sorry. Once you have decided the notation that you want, asking how to set that in TeX would be on topic.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: OK, it's a bit marginal still, but I retracted my close vote, thanks for the edit.

Comment: I'm not saying that I don't see the code repeating itself, but that the final file. I will give an example in the question.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setbox0\hbox{before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \emph{c} before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced as in \emph{church}
    \item \emph{g} \makebox[\the\wd0][c]{"}  as in \emph{gin}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}`?

Comment: You should add the words "ditto marks" to the title. Perhaps `Quote (ditto mards) to avoid repeating a text`. This would help search engines find the post, as I expect that many who would want to do this would seach for  "how to make ditto marks" or similar.

Comment: Done, thank you!

Comment: related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442650/138900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like this with package `eqparbox` (two variants):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \emph{c} \eqmakebox[NR]{before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced as in} \emph{church}
\item \emph{g} \eqmakebox[NR]{ — } \emph{gin}
\item \emph{g} \eqmakebox[NR][s]{ — — — } \emph{gin}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the width of the text and use it for a box of the same width that only contains, say, quotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setbox0\hbox{before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \emph{c} before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced as in \emph{church}
    \item \emph{g} \makebox[\the\wd0][c]{"}  as in \emph{gin}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And you can use macros to abbreviate it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setbox0\hbox{before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced}
\newcommand{\pft}{\makebox[\the\wd0][c]{"}\ }
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \emph{c} before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced as in \emph{church}
    \item \emph{g} \pft  as in \emph{gin}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestions are `//` or `<<`, each two characters. Why not three characters?

```
\newcommand{\QW}{before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced as in }
% ...
\item \emph{c} \QW \emph{church}
```

Choose whatever works for you as the two letter macro name.

While I was writing the above answer the questioner "clarified" the question. It turned out that the clarification nullified this answer to the original question.

EDIT

Here's another (long-winded) answer to your revised question. Use a `tabular`.

```
% repeatprob.tex SE 513244  avoid repeating text

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\MB}{$\bullet$}
\newcommand*{\RP}{------ '' ------}
% for even less text
\newcommand*{\Entry}[2]{\MB & \emph{#1} & \RP \emph{#2} \\}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{cccl}
$\bullet$ & \emph{c} & before \emph{e} or \emph{i} is pronounced as in & \emph{church} \\
\MB & \emph{g} & '' & \emph{gin} \\
\MB & \emph{g} & \RP & \emph{gin} \\
\Entry{g}{gin}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

GOM (Grumpy Old Man)

Comment: I guess you did not understand the question.

Comment: @Blincer I answered your original question before you changed it. Please remove the negative rating.

Comment: I didn't change it, I clarified it. You can check the comments where I have already explained that the csource was not the problem.

Comment: I cannot remove the vote until the answer is modified.

Comment: @Blincer I have extended my answer. It would have helped if your original question had included the clarification. Let's call a peace.

Comment: @Blincer Thank you for removing the negative rating. I have re-edited my answer to give an even more succinct input.