# Maximum number of questions in the alterqcm package?

Tags: alterqcm

I wrote a MCQ with an unusually large number of proposed answers (7 answers). I realize that it is not possible to propose more than 5 answers to a question.
How can the MCQ be able to offer more than 5 answers?

[image: MCQ]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,french]{article}  % Présentation générale et mise en page
\usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=FR}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
%macro from  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440382/package-eurosym-how-to-change-the-decimal-separator
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\EUR}[2][]{%
  \if@EURleft\euro\,\fi
  \num[#1]{#2}%
  \if@EURleft\else\,\euro\fi
}
\makeatother        
    
\usepackage{alterqcm} 


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
\begin{alterqcm}[lq=.7\columnwidth,num=false,symb = \dingsquare]
\AQquestion{problème 1}{%
{1},
{2},
{3},
{4}}
\AQquestion{problème 2}{%
{1},
{2},
{3},
{4},
{5}}
\AQquestion{problème 3 : choices 6 is invisible}{%
{1},
{2},
{3},
{4},
{5},
{6}}
\AQquestion{problème 4 : choices 6 and 7 are invisible}{%
{1},
{2},
{3},
{4},
{5},
{6},
{7}}
\end{alterqcm}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This modified `\AQquestion` command will show up to 7 answers.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,french]{article}  % Présentation générale et mise en page
\usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=FR}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
%macro from  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440382/package-eurosym-how-to-change-the-decimal-separator
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\EUR}[2][]{%
    \if@EURleft\euro\,\fi
    \num[#1]{#2}%
    \if@EURleft\else\,\euro\fi
}
\makeatother     

\usepackage{alterqcm} 

%****************************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\AQquestion}[3][]{%
    \setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}%
    \stepcounter{AQ@numquestion}% 
    \setcounter{AQ@numprop}{0} % v0.93
    \setcounter{aq@numb}{0}%
    \@for\liste:=#3\do{%
        \stepcounter{aq@numb}%
        \begingroup
        \ifnum\aqlocall@ng=3 \nogreekalph\fi
        \global\expandafter\let\csname aq@arg\alph{aq@numb}\endcsname\liste
        \endgroup}%
    \ifAQ@global@alea\ifAQ@global@VF%
    \else
    \aq@n@arg=0 %
    \loop\ifnum\aq@n@arg<\value{aq@numb}\aq@melange\advance\aq@n@arg by1\repeat\fi
    \fi
    \aq@adjust{#2}%
    \multirow{1}{\cmdAQ@global@lq}[\cmdAQ@local@pq]{%
        \ifAQ@global@num\aq@style@numquest{\cmdAQ@global@numstyle{AQ@numquestion}.}%
        \hspace{3pt}\fi%
        \ifAQ@global@transparent\hrule height0pt depth0pt width\aq@wdquest%
        \else#2\vss\fi%
    }%
    &\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}\aq@prop{\aq@arga}{1}\\%
    \ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi%
    &\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}\aq@prop{\aq@argb}{2}\\%
    \ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi%
    \ifnum\value{aq@numb}=2\hline\else\ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi%
    &\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}\aq@prop{\aq@argc}{3}\\%
    \ifnum\value{aq@numb}=3\hline\else\ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi%
    &\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}\aq@prop{\aq@argd}{4}\\%
    \ifnum\value{aq@numb}=4\hline\else\ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi%
    &\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}\aq@prop{\aq@arge}{5}\\%
    \ifnum\value{aq@numb}=5\hline\else\ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi%
    &\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}\aq@prop{\aq@argf}{6}\\%
    \ifnum\value{aq@numb}=6\hline\else\ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi%
    &\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}\aq@prop{\aq@argg}{7}\\% 
    \hline\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi%
}%
\makeatother
%****************************************************** 
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
        \begin{alterqcm}[lq=.7\columnwidth,num=false,symb = \dingsquare]
            \AQquestion{problème 1}{%
                {1},
                {2},
                {3},
                {4}}
            \AQquestion{problème 2}{%
                {1},
                {2},
                {3},
                {4},
                {5}
            }
            \AQquestion{problème 3 : choices 6 is visible}{%
                {1},
                {2},
                {3},
                {4},
                {5},
                {6}}
            \AQquestion{problème 4 : choices 6 and 7 are visible}{%
                {1},
                {2},
                {3},
                {4},
                {5},
                {6},
                {7}}
        \end{alterqcm}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is interesting, and limits it to 7 responses. Is it possible to make a loop (foreach or other) that does not limit the number of answers?

Comment: @AndréC The answer can be easily expanded to provide students with a reasonable number of responses.

Comment: Currently seven, but that's no longer the problem since you can easily extend your code. I'm just wondering on a computational level, if your code can be subject to a loop that works regardless of the number of responses. That is, if it is generalizable.

Comment: @AndréC  It can be done but this would be a programming question that will merit another question :).

Comment: Ok, so I accept your answer and will not go any further.

Comment: @AndréC  Thank you for your feedback!